# How to get the max between several value group per year

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am working on the stack overflow database and I would like to have the most popular tag per year. The output that I want is :

```
2016 Java 123456
2015 PHP  123456
2014 Java 123456
...  ...  ...
```

I have make this query :

```
SELECT tagName, annee, max(nbApparitions) AS nbApparitions
FROM  
    (SELECT tagName,
     year(creationDate) AS annee,
     count(tagName) AS nbApparitions
     FROM tags
     JOIN postTags 
     ON (tags.Id = postTags.tagId)
     JOIN posts
     ON (postTags.postId = posts.Id)
     GROUP BY tagName, year(creationDate))Apparition
 GROUP BY tagName , annee
```

But this query return all tags for each year. I don't know how to make this.

Comment: You can try to order by nbApparitions and fetch only the first row in the outer query. I don't know how this is written for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT tagname, annee, cnt
FROM (SELECT t.tagName, year(creationDate) AS annee,
             count(*) AS cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year(creationDate) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS seqnum
      FROM tags t JOIN
           postTags pt
           ON t.Id = pt.tagId JOIN
           posts p
           ON pt.postId = p.Id
      GROUP BY t.tagName, year(creationDate)
     ) pt
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

In statistics, the most common element is called the *mode*.  The above returns exactly one mode for each year.  If there are ties, then an arbitrary one is chosen.

If you want all modes when there are ties, then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

In English, "apparition" means "ghost", so the query is a bit funny.  That's why I changed the column name to `cnt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your explanations